# Question about the accuracy of the function matchtemplate

Tags: c++, opencv

To avoid syntax errors which might bring confusion to you,fistly I would like to clarify that I am just a first-year student from China who is struggling to find a solution and therefore seeking assistance here.(also please considering requester's limited programming knowledge).I have designed a simple C++ program to recognize the digits on an ID card. Firstly, I preprocess the ID card image and then segment it based on contours. The segmentation results are as expected. Then, I use the matchTemplate function with templates stored in a folder on my desktop. Unfortunately, the recognition is not very accurate, for example，0 may be recognized as 8.
Here is my algorithm about template match

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        string templatePath = "C:\\Users\\86188\\Desktop\\numbers\\" + to_string(j) + ".png";
        Mat templateImg = imread(templatePath, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        resize(templateImg, templateImg, Size(digitWidth, height));
        //imshow("处理后的模板" + to_string(j), templateImg);//在循环里展示要用to_string()语句，实际上是给每个窗口赋不同名称
        Mat result;
        matchTemplate(digitImg, templateImg, result, TM_CCORR_NORMED);
        double matchVal;
        minMaxLoc(result, nullptr, &matchVal, nullptr, nullptr);
        if (matchVal > maxMatchVal) {
            maxMatchVal = matchVal;
            maxMatchNum = to_string(j);
        }//这里都是索引算法，用来循环寻找最合适的匹配
    }
    matchedNumbers.push_back(maxMatchNum);// 将匹配的数字添加到容器中
}
```

[Here is one of the examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsSlb.png)
[separated numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhbrE.png)
[template example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahxbb.png)
I wish someone could point the limitations of my program and provide some solutions

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: do you mean that i should question at that site?sorry i am unfamiliar

Comment: Yes, this seems more suitable for one of those sites.